# Edit image preview is not showing

Tags: php, wordpress

I have create a `WordPress` project in my localhost and commit it in a `Git` repository

So I host this project in my `VPS` (So, occur change URL).

In my localhost not has this problem, but in my hosted project, when I try edit image, image preview is not showing

I checked `function.php` file in my theme if has any problem with `?>`, but is not normal, no have any empty line after php close tag, php tag is closed.

I guess, is any problem with change url, but I no have idea.

Comment: Did you check folders permission?

Comment: You have any error message about _functions.php_ ?

Comment: @ThiagoAugustusOliveira Is, my wp-content folder has permission 777

Comment: It's in a public repository?

Comment: @vard How to can I check error? I add define('WP_DEBUG', true) in my wp-config.php, but it look lick is not enable

Comment: I was asking that because you was talking about _functions.php_. Though you can check on your browser console for the ajax requests that display the media library and see if it returns a PHP error or an Error 500.

Comment: No has any error in browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this this problem installing `PHP GB`